# Save base64 bit encoded tring to the file in php

Tags: php, zend-framework, ffmpeg, base64

I have a php application which takes base64 encoded wav file from the client (browser) via ajax and save to the database. No I have to re encode the wav file using ffmpeg before I save the file in to the database (I can do this using system calls). But the questions is I need the input file (name.wav) for ffmpeg to do the work and as of right now I have only base64 encoded string in my php variable. I need to save this file to the disk using these base64 encoded string. How can I do this in php.

my server is running on RedHat and apache.

Thanks for your help in advance

Prabath

Comment: So.. what exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to decode the string and write it to a file:

```
file_put_contents('name.wav', base64_decode($data));
```

You can then pass `name.wav` to FFmpeg.

Comment: yes this worked, but I had to strip some meta data first. 

$file = str_replace('data:audio/wav;base64,', '', $file);

$tmpname = tempnam("/tmp", 'wave');

file_put_contents($tmpname, base64_decode($file));